# ¿Por qué "bajar/apear" a alguien del burro es "convencerlo de su error"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos

Existe una expresión coloquial que hace referencia a "no bajarse del burro" como "no reconocer el error" o no reconocer un punto de vista alternativo.

El DRAE la recoge en [la entrada de burro/a como](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6K7oz2e)

> apear a alguien del burro, o de la burra
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Convencerlo de su error.
>
> apearse alguien del burro, o de la burra
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Reconocer que ha errado en algo.

(nota, similares entradas hay para bajar/bajarse y caer/caerse)

Si en lugar de un burro fuera un caballo, esta expresión tendría un poco más de sentido, debido a su referencia a un pasaje bíblico. Me pregunto el porqué de que sea un burro.

¿Qué relación guarda no querer bajarse de un *burro* con no admitir o darse cuenta de un error?

Comment: ¿Porque si fuera un caballo tendría más sentido? Dentro de mi poco conocimiento de pasajes bíblicos tengo varios con burros(mula) pero no con caballos. (si tienes tiempo de explicar, gracias.)

Comment: @DGaleano (San) Pablo se cayó del caballo cuando iba camino a Damasco por una especie de revelación divina o epifanía que le hizo cambiar de ser el azote de los cristianos a convertirse al cristianismo. No es exactamente "asumir o reconocer un error", pero podría entender que "caerse del caballo" fuera "cambiar de mentalidad" o incluso "tener cuna revelación (cuasi)divina". Referencias a "reconocer el error" asociadas a burros, no recuerdo ninguna, ni en la biblia ni otros libros que haya leído.

Comment: Yo creo que es porque en algunos lugares se hace referencia a "burro" como a un animal torpe, por extensión se dice que una persona es burro(a) cuando es tonta. En consecuencia, apearse de un burro haría referencia a alguien que abandona la torpeza.

Comment: En Argentina *estar subido arriba del caballo* o *estar subido al poni* significa "creerse superior, darse aires", y *bajarse del caballo/poni* significa salir de esa actitud altiva. Siempre lo interpreté en relación a estar en un lugar alto (más alto que quien está de a pie). En inglés existe una expresión casi idéntica (*get off your high horse*).

Comment: @R0tten justo acababa de llegar a esa parte de la definición de Covarrubias cuando he leído tu comentario. Por cierto, impagable el principio de la definición. "ASNO, animal conocido, domestico y familiar, al hombre de mucho provecho y poco gasto: de grãde servicio, y que no da ruido, salvo quando rebuzna, que aquel rato es insufrible." Ya no se hacen diccionarios como los de antes...

Answer (score 2):

Honestamente, creo que la explicación es mucho más mundana. Resulta que el burro, a diferencia del caballo, tiene unas orejas largas que caen hacia delante. Estas funcionan como anteojeras, de modo que el burro, se dice, solamente puede ver de frente y no a los lados.

En realidad sí que puede ver a los lados, pero es solamente el dicho popular. De hecho, se le colocan anteojeras para forzar que realmente sólo vea de frente. Dejo aquí la definición de DRAE:

> **anteojera**
>
> 3. f. pl. En las guarniciones de las caballerías de tiro, piezas de vaqueta que caen junto a los ojos del animal, para que no vean por los
>    lados, sino de frente.
> 4. f. pl. Actitud mental o prejuicio que solo permite ver un aspecto limitado de la realidad.

Y la acepción 3 lleva al a cuarta. Bajar a alguien del burro (que "sólo camina de frente") para que pueda caminar hacia los lados (explorar otras opciones).

PD: tampoco es cierto que el burro camine solo de frente. De hecho, es típico el chiste de que "para hacer una carretera por el monte, suelta a un burro, que lo hará mejor que el ingeniero" jaja.

Answer (score 1):

La expresión "bajarse del burro/caballo" es sinónimo del "*reconocimiento del error*", "*cambio de discurso*" o "*conversión*".

Hace referencia al desvanecimiento sufrido por San Pablo cuando iba camino a Damasco para perseguir a los cristianos en la que quedó ciego. En Damasco, Jesús recuperó su vista e inmediatamente fue bautizado. Se dió cuenta de que en vez de perseguir a los cristianos, debía proclamar la fe.

**¿Por qué del burro y no del caballo?**

Ambas expresiones - caerse del burro y caerse del caballo - se usan. Se alude al burro siempre que se quiere destacar que son protagonistas la rudeza y el poco entendimiento. ([*Véase. burro*](https://dle.rae.es/asno#JPb0gc3)).

> San Pablo cayó del caballo camino de Damasco.
>
> D.Trump baja del burro y reconoce su derrota electoral tras el
> asalto al Capitolio.

La conversión de San Pablo o caída en el camino de Damasco, está citado en la Biblia (Hechos de los apóstoles, 9, 1-18;1​ Primera epístola a los corintios 15, 8-92).

En el arte se retrata la conversión de San Pablo con una caída sobre el caballo o burro camino a Damasco; Artistas como Rubens, Caravaggio o Miguel Ángel.

[image: Conversión de San Pablo (Caravaggio)]

Cito un hilo de foro del Instituto Cervantes:

> "Caerse caballo o del burro es lo que le pasó a San Pablo cuando iba
> camino de Damasco a perseguir a los cristianos y sufrió un
> desvanecimiento o algo similar y se dio cuenta que en realidad su
> deber era proclamar la fe en Jesús"

(Sebastián Santoyo García, https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=43775)

Comment: Buen hallazgo! Parece que Alfred López [está de acuerdo con esta explicación](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-proviene-decir-caer-del-burro-para-indicar-que-alguien-se-ha-dado-cuenta-que-estaba-errado/).

Answer (score 0):

La explicación es intuitiva, porque

> apear de un burro a alguien

directamente alude al acto de corregirlo, de hacerlo `caer en la cuenta` de un error.

Aún sin referencias eruditas o contexto histórico, la expresión resulta entendible para cualquier hispano hablante, ya que contiene en si misma la potencia ilustrativa  de hacer `bajar a tierra`, de hacer `entrar en razón`, de lograr que alguien se de cuenta de la equivocación o torpe ignorancia sobre la que (figuradamente) cabalga.

El uso de la palabra [apear](https://dle.rae.es/apear?m=form) contiene la alusión directa el efecto de`desmontar`, en este caso, desarmar el equívoco o mentira. Véase que entre las acepciones de la palabra apear (`bajar a alguien`), existe la referencia al uso coloquial, de

> Disuadir a alguien de sus opiniones, ideas, creencias, suposiciones, etc. No pude apearle de su propósito. U. t. c. prnl.
> Blockquote

*Bajarlo/apearlo del **burro*** —animal que es sinónimo extendido de necio o ignorante— es por tanto **desbaratar su posición de necedad o confusión**. Véase que en el mismo sentido, también es corriente el uso del verbo`desasnar` (o desburrar)

> [desasnar](https://dle.rae.es/desasnar?m=form)
>
> De des- y asno.
>
> 1. tr. coloq. Hacer perder a alguien la rudeza, o quitarle la rusticidad por medio de la enseñanza. U. t. c. prnl.